# What might be causing 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8081' error when invoking remote method from Electron application?

Tags: axios, electron

I have an application with Electron (13.6.9). I have created an event (called 'axios') that I call to launch requests to an API in IIS (PHP). The call works perfectly for me locally, but when I upload the application to my server I get an error:

Error: Error invoking remote method 'axios': Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8081
at EventEmitter.i.invoke (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:73)

I understand that it might be a port (8081?) issue during the invocation, but I haven't been able to find any information about it.

**Event definition (index.js)**

```
ipcMain.handle('axios', async (_, token = null, type, uri, body = null, headers = {}) => {
    const result = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {      
        if (uri.slice(-1) == '/' || uri.indexOf('/?') > 0) {
          console.error('Estimtrack Error: Please correct this url ' + uri + ' and remove the last slash "/" it will not work in production due to https cross origin problems with the api.')
        }

        var cacheHeaders = {
          'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache',
          'Pragma': 'no-cache',
          'Authorization': token
        }

        var localHeaders = {
          headers: cacheHeaders,
          method: type,
          url: uri
        }
        let mergedHeaders = Object.assign({}, localHeaders, headers)

        if (body != null) {
          mergedHeaders.data = body
        }
        axios(mergedHeaders)
          .then(response => {
            resolve(response)
          }).catch(e => {
            reject(e)
        })
      })           

      return { data: result.data }
})
```

**Invocation**

```
import store from '../store'
import axios from 'axios'
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

const estimtrackAxios = {

  install (Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$estimtrackAxios = function (type, uri, body = null, headers = {}) {
      return ipcRenderer.invoke('axios', 
                                store.getters.getAccessToken, 
                                type, 
                                store.getters.getFrontOption("SERVER_API") + uri,
                                body,
                                headers)   
                        .then ((value) => {
                            return value
                        })                       
    }
  }
}
export default estimtrackAxios
```

I would like to know what this error is due to, and if it seems to have something to do with port 8081.

****Trace****

```
http://172.17.53.43:9185/api/quirofans/mac_address/00:50:56:8f:30:19
C:\captis-pre\CaptisDeviceFront\resources\app.asar\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:8699 Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools
C:\captis-pre\CaptisDeviceFront\resources\app.asar\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.dev.js:8706 You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
renderer.js:15 Error: Error invoking remote method 'axios': Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8081
    at EventEmitter.i.invoke (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:73)
renderer.js:15 Error Error: Error invoking remote method 'axios': Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8081
    at EventEmitter.i.invoke (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:73)
```

Comment: From what it seems, `axios` is attempting to connect to the URL `8081`, which is - of course - not a valid URL by itself. More of your stack trace would help here. From just looking at your samples, could you check what `store.getters.getFrontOption("SERVER_API")` returns?

Comment: Thanks in advance for your answer. I have put the trace of `store.getters.getFrontOption("SERVER_API") + uri` (first line) and the address is good, I have checked it with Postman and it returns the expected result (JSON).